# Difference between mlocate and plocate

Tags: locate

Since `locate` doesn't work by default in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, and the message on the terminal says:

```
Command 'locate' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install plocate
```

As we can see, it says that we can install it with `sudo apt install plocate`.

I want to know the difference between `mlocate` and `plocate` so that I can decide which one to install.

Answer (score 8):

[`plocate`](https://plocate.sesse.net/) is backwards-compatible with `mlocate`, and is much faster and more efficient than `mlocate`.

In fact you don’t have a choice between `mlocate` and `plocate` in Ubuntu 22.04: if you install the former, you’ll end up with the latter anyway, because [`mlocate` is a transitional package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mlocate) which pulls in [`plocate`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/plocate).

Comment: According to plocate.sesse.net, it uses an inverted index over trigrams (combinations of 3 bytes) in search strings, which allows it to rapidly narrow down the set of candidates to a very small list, instead of linearly scanning through every entry.